# Adminform uploaded file preview

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, file-upload, image-preview

I added file upload input in AdminHtml Block like this below.

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'document',
            'file',
            [
                'name' => 'document',
                'label' => __('Document'),
                'title' => __('Document'),
                'required'  => false,
                 'renderer'  => 'Mymodule\Mak\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer\Document',
            ]
        );
```

I called the preview like this below

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\Mak\Block\Adminhtml\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\Object as Instance;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
class Document extends AbstractRenderer
{
    
    private $_storeManager;
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, 
StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
       $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
   }
   /**
    * Renders grid column
    *
    * @param Instance $row
    * @return  string
    */
   public function render($row)
   {
       $row = Instance;    
       $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.'cart2quote/images/'.$this->_getValue($row);
       return '<h1>'.$this->_getValue($row).'</h1>';
   }
 }
```

But the render is not working

Comment: Hey,have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add like below to show preview of image. While saving any pdf/doc file you have to convert it into png/jpeg format.

```
$fieldset->addType('custom_image','PackageName\Module\Helper\Image');
    
$fieldset->addField(
    'pdf_file',
    'custom_image',
    [
        'name' => 'pdf_file',
        'label' => __('Document'),
        'title' => __('Document'),
        'required'  => false,
    ]
);
```

Now create file Image.php under path PackageName/Module/Helper

```
<?php

namespace PackageName\Module\Helper;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
{
    public function _getUrl() {   

        $pdfFileInfo = pathinfo($this->getValue());
        $thumb = $pdfFileInfo['dirname'].'/'.$pdfFileInfo['filename'].'.png';
        return $thumb;
    }
}

?>
```

My save.php controller like below, i am uploading pdf file and converting pdf file into png format for preview.

```
<?php

namespace PackageName\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Module;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends Action
{
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'PackageName_Module::timberconnection_searchdata';

    protected $searchdataCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploader,
        \PackageName\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\CollectionFactory $searchdataCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
        $this->searchdataCollectionFactory = $searchdataCollectionFactory;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) 
        {
            try {

                if (isset($_FILES['pdf_file']) && isset($_FILES['pdf_file']['name']) && strlen($_FILES['pdf_file']['name'])) 
                {
                    $base_media_path = 'ael/uploadpdf';
                    $uploader = $this->uploader->create(['fileId' => 'pdf_file']);
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf', 'doc', 'docx','png']);
                    $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($base_media_path));
                    $postData['pdf_file'] = $base_media_path . $result['file'];

                    /* Create Thumbnail for PDF */
                    $pdfWithPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($base_media_path).$result['file'];
                    $pdfFileInfo = pathinfo($pdfWithPath);
                    $thumb = $pdfFileInfo['dirname'].'/'.$pdfFileInfo['filename'].'.png';
                    $command = 'convert '.$pdfWithPath.' -colorspace RGB -geometry 800 '.$thumb;

                    exec($command);

                } else {
                    if (isset($postData['pdf_file']) && isset($postData['pdf_file']['value'])) {
                        if (isset($postData['pdf_file']['delete'])) {
                            $postData['pdf_file'] = '';
                        } elseif (isset($postData['pdf_file']['value'])) {
                            $postData['pdf_file'] = $postData['pdf_file']['value'];
                        } else {
                            $postData['pdf_file'] = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

                $searchdataModel = $this->_objectManager->create('PackageName\Module\Model\Module');                 
                $searchdataModel->setData($postData);
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                if(isset($id))
                    $searchdataModel->setId($id);

                $searchdataModel->save();

                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the searchdata.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFilterModuleData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $searchdataModel->getId()]);
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')
                    ->setFilterModuleData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
                $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        }

        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Output in my case :- https://prnt.sc/11pdm9c

Please check and let me know if you face any issue.